# Installing PL/Ruby on PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I'd like to use the PL/Ruby procedural languages but it seems the git repository is not very well maintained:
https://github.com/Absolight/postgresql-plruby/tree/fixup-9-3

When I get to creating the new language:

```
create function plruby_call_handler() returns language_handler
as '/var/lib/postgresql/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/plruby'
language 'c'; -- Warning: the 'c' has to be lowercase, unlike the example on git.
```

I get the following error:

```
 ERROR:  could not load library "/var/lib/postgresql[...]plruby": undefined symbol: plruby_s_load
```

I'm using Ruby 2.1.4 with PostgreSQL 9.3 on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Could you specify which OS you're using for your PostgreSQL server?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10, question updated.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you are compiling that source from branch fixup-9-3 and run postgresql version 9.3

```
  git clone https://github.com/Absolight/postgresql-plruby.git
  cd postgresql-plruby
  git checkout fixup-9-3
```

Because I had almost same problem when installing from master branch. Also try to install libpq-dev. I am using OSX 10.10 all I need to do to install PostgreSQL library was `brew install postgresql` and this worked on my machine.